# SQL SELECT FROM WHERE FirstName > "Maria"

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
 First Name
 Bryce
 Marcellin
 Caroline
 Kerry 
 Roberto 
 Mary
 Carol
 Warren
 Bonnie
 Terry
 Louis 
 Michelle
 Bobby 
 Tony
 Vic
 Frank
 Roberto 
 Jose 
 Doug
 Brian
 William
 Aiden
 Davis
```

What exactly does SELECT FirstName FROM Members WHERE FirstName > "Maria"; search for ? in particular, the WHERE statement. 
It returns the names:

Roberto, Mary, Warren, Terry, Michelle, Tony, Vic, Roberto and William

I thought it was searching for FirstName strings that are longer than 5 characters but this is not the case since Tony and Vic are also returned.

Comment: you want exactly 'Maria'

Comment: Name greater then Maria ... wat??  wat u exactly want... explain in simple English

Comment: Sql server or Mysql choose one

Comment: do you mean the character count ?

Comment: @vikramsharma well since its not >= I dont ...

Comment: you should use regular expression

Comment: @Umair I'm trying to translate this into english but as the answer from Jhecht  says I want all the names that are in alphabetical order AFTER "maria"

Comment: @NoDisplayName I apologize I meant mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It searches for terms that are in alphabetical order AFTER "Maria."

For example, with "Jack, James, Jim"  if you searched for `SELECT name FROM table WHERE first_name >= 'James'` you would receive the results of 'James' and 'Jim', since alphabetically those two are after one another. The reason Vic, Robert, William, etc are returned is because they are alphabetically after the value of "Maria"

Comment: yes this is what I meant, I just figured it out right now. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Maria's string length is 5 characters, so use length function to find [length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) of individual names and check it to be greater than 5 as below:

```
SELECT FirstName 
FROM Members 
WHERE length(FirstName) > 5;
```

Or if your name is going to be dynamic, you could use like:

```
SELECT FirstName 
FROM Members 
WHERE length(FirstName) > length("Maria");
```

If you need all names that comes after Maria and length greater than 5 then use:

```
SELECT FirstName 
FROM Members 
WHERE FirstName > 'Maria';
AND   length(FirstName) > length('Maria');
```